# Hibernate doesn't show SQL values

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot application. Here my `application.properties` file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS TEST
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
server.port=8080
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
```

When I save some data I have output as below

```
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        project.staff
        (school_name, tc) 
    values
        (?, ?)
```

I can't see the parameters which sent to DB. I have another API and it returns parameters as below

```
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        price
        (brand_id, curr) 
    values
        (default, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2023-12-31 20:19:54.914 TRACE 47712 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [1]
2023-12-31 20:19:54.914 TRACE 47712 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [EUR]
```

I have tried `logging.level.org.hibernate.type=trace` and it also didn't work.

I have checked multiple times `application.properties` file but I can't see the difference and I couldn't understand the problem. What I am missing to have parameters on logging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the following logging properties to log SQL queries and parameters:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG  
logging.level.org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind=TRACE
```

Comment: I still do not have expected output. The output `2024-01-01T20:22:35.902+01:00 TRACE 20489 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind              : binding parameter (1:VARCHAR) <- [string]`  I want to see what is the value of String

Comment: The actual values are logged for me with these log levels. Are you sure the value 'string' is not being used in the query?
```2024-01-02 01:43:47 TRACE [tomcat-handler-37] o.h.t.d.JdbcBindingLogging: binding parameter (2:VARCHAR) <- [%dog%]```

Comment: My bad. You were right. Could you explain why it didn't work without `...SQL` and `....bind`? I have another API and it work fine only with `spring.jpa.show-sql=true`?

Comment: Do you have a log4j.xml or the like in your project? If so, does it declare loggers for the hibernate classes that enable this logging?

Comment: No, I don't have any of them in my any of project

Comment: Not sure why it works in your project with only '''show-sql=true''. That only controls if the SQL statements themselves are logged (without parameter values).